# SonarQube Violation Java 8 Bifunction Requirement

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, sonarqube, functional-interface

I defined a functional interface with one method declaration, and the implementation of the method in a class of another project. SonarQube violation is that I am redefining a standard functional interface that is already provided in Java 8.

```
@FunctionalInterface
/*access modifier*/ interface XYZService {
   XYZProfile makeRESTServiceGetCall(String str, Integer id);
}

"Drop this interface in favor of "java.util.function.BiFunction<String,Integer,XYZProfile>"Drop this interface in favor of "java.util.function.BiFunction<String,Integer,XYZProfile>"
```

The REST service GET call simply takes the inputs and returns `XYZProfile`. Generally, the project structure requires the using interfaces, but to solve the Sonar violations shall I remove the 'interface', and change the `makeRESTServiceGetCall` method call to the bifunction syntax?

Comment: You didn’t ask a question. You just appended a question mark to a statement.

Answer (score 0):

The violation suggests that there is already a Functional Interface that can solve the purpose of what you're trying to implement using your custom interface i.e. [`BiFunction<T,U,R>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/BiFunction.html).

So at places where you're defining the method `makeRESTServiceGetCall` of your `XYZService`, you can instead simply create a `BiFunction` in your code as:

```
BiFunction<String, Integer, XYZProfile> xyzProfileBiFunction = (string, integer) -> {
    return xyzProfile; // the GET call implementation using 'string' &'integer'      
};
```

and then at places where you were calling the method `makeRESTServiceGetCall`, you can simply [`apply`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/BiFunction.html#apply(T,U)) the above implementation as :

```
XYZProfile xyzProfileNullPointer = xyzProfileBiFunction.apply("nullpointer", 0);
XYZProfile xyzProfileParth = xyzProfileBiFunction.apply("Parth", 1);
```